# Determine whether a function is surjective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

So say you have the function ${f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}}$, and want to determine whether $f(m, n)=2m-n$ is a surjective function.

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGwIzKlJN8A) online, which he then proves it. The part I don't understand is why the proof works. In the video, he gets to $f(0, -y) = 2(0)-(-y)=y$, but I don't understand how that proves ${f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}}$.

Same with the function $f(m, n)=m^2-n^2$, I found [this answer](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/determine-whether-f-z-z-z-is-onto-if/) online, but it looks like $f(m, n)=m^2-n^2$ is not a surjective function. But doesn't the function just have to output an integer? Why can't something like $m=2$ and $n=4$ work?

Comment: What is the definition of a surjective function?

Comment: You have to prove every $y\in\mathbb Z$ is mapped to by $f$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f(m,n)=2m-n$, the goal is to find for every $y\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $f(m,n)=y$, but as mentionned $f(0,-y)=y$ and thus $(m,n)=(0,-y)$ works, we thus have : $\forall y\in\mathbb{Z},\exists (m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2,y=f(m,n)$. As for $f(m,n)=m^2-n^2$, I don't understand what you mean by "doesn't the function just have to output an integer? Why can't something like m=2 and n=4 work?". The question is "does $f(m,n)$ takes all possible values in $\mathbb{Z}$ ?", the answer is no because $f(m,n)\neq 2$ for all $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ as proved in the answer. It is of course not sufficient to say that $f(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$, take $n\in\mathbb{Z}\mapsto\mapsto |n|\in\mathbb{Z}$ which is clearly not surjective.

Comment: Oh I get it! When you flipped the question around ("does (,) takes all possible values in ℤ") and said (,)≠2, it all made sense! Looks like I was understanding it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because taking $\forall y \in \mathbb{Z}$ exists pair  $f(0,-y)=y$.